# Lettuce and spring-data-redis version compatibility

Tags: compatibility, spring-data-redis, lettuce

Is there any compatibility matrix avaiable for `spring-data-redis` and `lettuce` libraries?

Comment: Can I please expect the comments for the close votes?

Comment: I found the maven repo to be the place where this mapping is provided for each `spring-data-redis` package. So from `spring-boot-starter-parent`, we can lookup the dependency with `spring-data` and then look inside maven repo to find the appropriate `lettuce` version. Unless anybody else can share a better way/resource, I'll promote this to an answer.

Comment: Any solution (even if it's a bit non-trivial) would be nice to have, cause I found from experience that incompatible spring-data-redis and lettuce versions can be a real pain to work with... So it would be great if you could put this in an answer with a bit more explanation, cause I didn't quite get exactly how you get that info from the maven repo :/